# CSS border around div larger than the page width

Tags: css, html

I have an HTML div with a border around it. I've added a white-space: nowrap property to this div so that it will simply grow horizontally with the content (even past the page width). However, the border never extends beyond the page width, running right through the content. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/mHjRf/

HTML:

```
<div id=test>
    Content exceeding page width
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding `display: inline-block;` to your element styles:

```
#test {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mHjRf/2/